# LumiSoft.Net: How to access email public folders?

Tags: c#, .net, email, imap, lumisoft

I'm writing a C# forms application that uses `LumiSoft.Net` dll to connect to an email address using IMAP. I can connect to `INBOX` or any other folder in the email address, but I can not connect to public folders. The only method that this library has for this type of action is:

```
public void SelectFolder(string folder)
```

which works fine for `INBOX`, for example, but raises an exception when I'm trying to access public folders (`NO STATUS Cannot access folder 'Public Folders'`).

Is there a way to access public folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because IMAP server refuses to access 'Public Folders'.
This is because one of the two:
1) 'Public Folders' not selectable folder.
2) Not suffcient permissions to access that folder.

As you can guess "NO STATUS Cannot access folder ..." is server returned response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can access 'Public Folders' using any email client(e.g. Thunderbird), so I have sufficient permissions. Is there a way to access a specific sub-folder contained in the 'Public Folders', if this folder is flagged as not selectable ?